# What's the problem with looping through an object properties and then through each of its properties as well in this case?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, loops, object, iteration

I have an object with some arrays inside. Arrays on the other hand are populated with objects. The idea is to loop through the object and through the array on each iteration.

**Object:**

```
{trendingMovies: Array(20), popularMovies: Array(20), topRatedMovies: Array(20), upcomingMovies: Array(20), nowPlayingMovies: Array(20)}
```

*Arrays are populated with objects!*

```
// context
import { MoviesDataContext } from "../../context/Context-Config";

export default function SearchBar(props) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const movies = useContext(MoviesDataContext);
  const trendMovies = movies?.trendingMovies;

  const applyFilter = () => {
    props.searching.setFilter(() => {
      if (location.pathname === "/night-owl") {
        return trendMovies.filter((show) =>
          show.original_title.toLowerCase().includes(props.searching.search)
        );
      } else if (location.pathname === "/night-owl/movies") {
        const results = [];
        for (const property in movies) {
          results.push(
            movies[property].filter((show) => {
              show.original_title
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(props.searching.search);
            })
          );
        }
        return results;
      }
    });
  };
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: what is setfilter and searching in props what do they do? it would help if I can get a sandbox.

Comment: setFilter()  creates a new filtered array (for search results).

Comment: the components receives props object -> searching={{ search, handleSearch, setFilter }}

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not returning the filtered array inside the filter callback function.
2. In the `for-in` loop, you are pushing an array of filtered objects to the results array, but each element of the results array will contain an array of objects instead of a flat array of objects. I'm not sure if this is the desired format.

To fix these issues:

```
const results = [];
for (const property in movies) {
  const filtered = movies[property].filter((show) =>
    show.original_title.toLowerCase().includes(props.searching.search)
  );
  results.push(...filtered);
}
return results;
```